# Simple circuit to cut voltage below 14V

Tags: power-supply, batteries, relay, diy, bms

I would like to power a DIY bluetoothbox from a Bosch Professional 18v battery but they do not have a BMS as far as I know. So I need a way to cut off all energy drawn from the battery as soon as the voltage drops below like 14V and only turn on again if the battery is charged again and maybe a button is pressed.

I know that there are cheap BMS online but the one I tried did not store my set cut off voltage when disconnecting the battery and has things like a voltage display which I do not need. Other BMS I found online where stillt drawing some current when the power was cut off.

So is there a simple circuit I can make myself which uses minimal power and cuts the power completly when the voltage is below 14V?

Comment: One of the common solutions is to use a comparator and a latching circuit to make sure the circuit doesn't start up again by itself i.e. even if the battery voltage rises to some required level the system requires a power cycle.

Comment: What is "minimal power"? How much current is acceptable during power cut-off?

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach is based on Schmitt trigger that gives output Low (M2 off) under 14V Vbatt and output High (M2 on) after Vbatt reach 16V again after some charging.
All is just two opamps in one package and couple of passives.
Use low power op-amp and low power reference.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4Tgwz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That sounds great, I will try it. Thank you.